# Trying to install opencv with pip but I keep getting errors

Tags: python, machine-learning, pip, opencv

Installing python module opencv using `pip install python-opencv` in the vs-code terminal but I got an error so I tried `pip install python-opencv-headless` and still got the same error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-opencv-headless
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-opencv-headless

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

you got an error saying the package doesn't exist.

the package is named `opencv-python`, not python-opencv.